# Adding 'public/index.php' to all requests without changing url

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to add `public/index.php` to all request using .htaccess

I tried like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /public/index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

but it didn't changed ..

Example :

If i type

```
localhost/project/first
```

it should request

```
localhost/project/public/index.php/first
```

What is the issue in my `.htaccess` ?

Comment: Remove the leading slash from pattern.

Comment: You mean like this ? https://eval.in/429241

Answer (score 1):

You can use a rule like this in `/project/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php/$1 [L]
```

And this is `/project/public/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/public/

RewriteRule index\.php$ - [L,NC]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [L,R=301,NE]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

`RewriteCond` are required to avoid rewriting for real files and directories. And There shouldn't be any leading slash in `RewriteRule` pattern in .htaccess. `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

Comment: Thanks, there is another .htaccess under a folder named `public` .. here it is ..https://eval.in/429259 will that affect this one.. bcoz this is not requesting properly..

Comment: And where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: this is at the root i.e., inside `localhost/project/.htaccess`